# OpenStack in VM player

Tags: virtualbox, maas, openstack

Hello guys I'm looking for some help or pointers on using ubuntu maas.

I'm running my master node in a vm and I want to tried and add more virtual nodes to my cluster, however when I try to add the node it does not appear in the cluster.

I had found a good link but I'm using a different laptop atm and was hoping that someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks, Leprejohn

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you found:
https://insights.ubuntu.com/2015/01/15/virtualbox-extensions-for-maas/

More generally speaking, you'll need to set up your virtual networks with careful consideration for DHCP & DNS as mentioned in that post and in the MAAS docs.

Comment: Presuming you're on MAAS 1.7, here are some docs related to your question.  
...
 - Setting up: https://maas.ubuntu.com/docs1.7/index.html#setting-up-a-maas-server
  
 - Adding nodes: https://maas.ubuntu.com/docs1.7/nodes.html